# Facebook Website HTML Content Parsing in english language

Tags: c#, wpf

I was trying to parse facebook website html content page and I have done it, but I got html page document language in different type I want it in english language,

eg : I got the html page like `<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="te" id="facebook".....`

But I want it like `<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en" id="facebook......"`

Code:

```
HtmlWeb objWeb = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument objDoc = objWeb.Load(Url);
string htmldoc = objDoc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```

Please suggest me how can i do that?

Comment: How about sending the right [**Accept-Language** HTTP header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Request_fields)?

Comment: I dont have any idea about Accept-Language

Comment: Maybe this is too obvious: How about doing research and gaining knowledge thus getting an idea about Accept-Language?

Comment: Yes It usefull for me, I will R&D on this . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

County information usually gets sent with the URL.

The url can contain locale information.

Www.domainName.com/en-GB/index

So essentially go to facebook, click the link to change the site to English, if it hasn't already done this, and copy the English url containing the the current url parameters.